# CORS 405 Method Not Allowed even though I have the right headers (I think)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need some more eyes on this.  My preflight request is failing with 405 Method Not Allowed.

As far as I can tell it should be working.  Here's my request:

```
OPTIONS http://diffDomain/spf/v1/user/user@example.com/password/change 
HTTP/1.1
Host: diffDomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.example.com/appName/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,es-US;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 02:06:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, api_key, Authorization, Accept
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

I'm waiting for access to the server so that I can add Access-Control-Request-Method to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` line.  Would that help?

I just need some eyes, because I've been debugging this for a few hours today and I don't have access to the server yet.

When I do as @sideshowbarker suggested below i get:

```
> curl -i -X OPTIONS http://diffDomain.com/spf/v1/user/user@example.com/password/change
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 21:25:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, api_key, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type, api_key, Authorization, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Origin
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Try  sending an OPTIONS request manually to that endpoint & see what you get; e.g., with curl from the command line: `curl -i -X OPTIONS http://diffDomain/spf/v1/user/user@example.com/password/change`. I suspect you’ll find 405 in the first line of the response you get back from that. And if so, that indicates a problem a problem that has nothing to do with your CORS config but instead is a more-fundamental problem: the server just is not configured to respond correctly to OPTIONS requests, at all. So any fix needs to start with getting the server to respond with 200 OK to any OPTIONS request

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for that. You may be right, except when I did that the server returned a 500 error as opposed to a 405 error.  See my comment above.

Comment: OK yeah that’s a bit unexpected but regardless, it confirms something needs fixing in that server. You should never be able to cause a 500 from a server just be sending it an OPTIONS request. So anyway, as far as next steps, it seems like you probably want to look in the server logs on the server side there, and see what information the server might be logging there about the cause of the internal server failure that resulted in the server sending that 500. Because a 500 pretty much always indicates an internal server failure (unless the server is misconfigured to send 500 for other cases…)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your backend looks like, but what I would suggest you is to add a middleware that intercepts every OPTIONS and return a 200 response and moving to the next request.

To clarify here is a [post](https://medium.com/@neo/handling-xmlhttprequest-options-pre-flight-request-in-laravel-a4c4322051b9) about this issue with Laravel based APIs.

I hope it helps.